# SQL select values containing only special characters

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Please help me with a query that returns all the records that contain at least one special character (ie, not just alphanumeric characters). Let's assume, that it is not possible to specify a list of all the possible special characters.

So from DB values

> qwe
>
> Asd1
>
> zxc!
>
> rTY
>
> dfg
>
> c-b

I need to get

> zxc!
>
> c-b

Hmmm...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `REGEXP` to Find not only alphanum chars

```
SELECT c FROM yourTable
WHERE c NOT REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/219b7b/2)

Comment: Fantastic! It works great. Thank you so much friend :)

Comment: It's my pleasure :)